# Delete data from a file and array

Tags: c++

The function I created deletes the data from the array only, I need it to delete data from the array and file, I don't know where is the mistake or the missing thing.

`customer_details` is the struct name.

```
void DeleteCustmer(customer_details customer[], int& counter)
    {
        ofstream outFile; //declaratin of thr file
        
        outFile.open(customer_file.c_str(),ios::app);
     
     if(outFile.is_open())
     {
        int room_id = 0;
        int delet_room, delet_index;
```

`counter` to check if is there any data inside the array.

```
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter the customer number you want to delete: ";
            cin >> delet_room;
            outFile << delet_room <<endl;
```

this line is to search inside the array.

```
            sort_fun(customer, counter);
            delet_index = binarySearch(customer, 0, counter + 1, delet_room);
```

.

```
            if (delet_index == -1) 
            {
                cout << "there is no customer in this room ";
            }
```

to delete the empty index.

```
            else 
            {
    
                for (int j = delet_index; j < counter - 1; j++)
                {
                    customer[j].id = customer[j + 1].id;
                    customer[j].name = customer[j + 1].name;
                    customer[j].age = customer[j + 1].age;
                    customer[j].gender = customer[j + 1].gender;
                    customer[j].nights = customer[j + 1].nights;
                    customer[j].room_id = customer[j + 1].room_id;
                    customer[j].bill = customer[j + 1].bill;
                }
                    counter--;
            }  
        }
            
        else
        {
            cout << "there is no employees to delete " <<endl;
        }
            
    }
    
     outFile.close();
    
    cout<<" \n Data has deleted successfully \n";
    
    }
```

Comment: `c++11` `c++14` or `c++17` one is enough.

Comment: One simple way to modify a file is to read all its contents into memory, and then rewrite it back out again, but without the data you want removed. Or, since you already seem to have all the data in your "array", just write out its contents to the file after you removed the element from the array?

Comment: this code makes no attempt to delete anything from the file. it opens the file in append mode and then writes the customer number to be deleted to it. Do you expect that to do something magic to the file?